# Rails asset pipeline, CSS file I added (but not required) is not precompiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I added a file named `mobile.css` into my assets/stylesheets directory. This file is not required in application.css as I only explicitly add it by pages I want optimized for mobile. When I run `rake assets:precompile` it doesn't push it into the asset pipeline. I'm going to guess if I add it to `application.css` it'll precompile, but then my mobile stylesheet will override the default stylesheet which I do not want.

Works great in development mode with the following in my layout:

```
- if mobile_device?
      = stylesheet_link_tag "mobile"
```

In production this is a no go as mobile.css is not getting added to the pipeline.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Just to cover the basics, all the other stylesheets are compiled correctly, and you remembered to add mobile.css to the appropriate templates?

Comment: Updated my question to answer your question.

Comment: Not sure if it's a possibility for you but I would suggest differentiating your conflicting css tags e.g. `#mobile #container` and just `#container` for everything else - not a great solution but might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always add it manually to the precompile array in your `application.rb`.

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( mobile.css )
```

Rule of thumb as far as the asset pipeline is concerned: if it's not required in a manifest OR it's not in the precompile array, it's not going to be precompiled.